# Redireccion múltiple usando .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Actualmente tengo una instrucción para crear URLs de este modo:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ pagina.php?valor1=$1&valor2=$2&valor3=$3&valor4=$4[L]
```

Con este tipo de regla se han generado mas de 5000 URLs. La pregunta es que ahora quiero modificar la URL para que ahora sea de esta manera:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/xxxxx-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$
```

Pero claro las antiguas paginas indexadas dejarían de funcionar y no puedo hacer una redirección de cada una de las 5000 URLs que dejarían de funcionar.

¿Existe alguna manera de ponerlo para que esas URL ya indexadas acudan a la nueva RewriteRule?

Las paginas ya indexadas entraran por xx/xx/xx/xx y quiero que vayan a xx/xx/xx/yyyy-xx sin tener que hacer un redirect de cada una de ellas.

Comment: Deberías empezar por la más restrictiva a menos y usar la opción `L` para que sea la última (veo que, al menos, usas esa opción para la primera que creaste). ¿Podrías compartir el contenido de `.htaccess` tal y como lo tienes (aunque no funcione) para reproducir el problema e indicarte la forma exacta de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Apache analiza cada una de las condiciones y reglas de redirección en el orden en el que se las encuentra, por lo que la solución es agregarlas en el orden adecuado en el archivo `.htaccess`: de condición más restrictiva a menos restrictiva.

De esta manera la menos restrictiva no eclipsará a la más restrictiva.

A continuación te muestro un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:

```
# Regla más restrictiva
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/xxxxx-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ otra_pagina.php?valor1=$1&valor2=$2&valor3=$3&valor4=$4 [L]

# Regla genérica
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ pagina.php?valor1=$1&valor2=$2&valor3=$3&valor4=$4 [L]
```

La primera regla, si se cumple, será la última en comprobarse (por usar la bandera `L`). En caso de que no se cumpla se comprobará la segunda como anteriormente se hacía.

Comment: Si, pero cuando me venga una url: yy/yy/yy/yy quiero que me vaya a yy/yy/yy/xxxxx-yy No se si me explico correctamente.

Comment: Eso no lo pusiste en la pregunta. Si editas tu pregunta incluyendo ese detalle editaré mi respuesta para incluir ese dato.

Comment: Editado en el primer post

Comment: ¿Quieres que se realice la redirección a nivel de navegador o que internamente use `$1`, `$2`, etc como si el producto no tuviera los `xxxxx` en la URL?

Comment: La idea es que la redireccion la haga el servidor

Comment: Estoy leyendo bien tu pregunta me estoy dando cuenta que el usuario no teclea los `yyyy`, si no que debe agregarlos el servidor. ¿Atendiendo a qué? Sólo se puede elegir a dónde enviar una petición cuando está tecleada por el usuario. Si hay "inteligencia" adicional de parte del servidor entoces debes desarrollarlo en tu código.

Comment: Es decir, ¿el `yyyy` de tu ejemplo es fijo o es variable?

Comment: Te lo pongo sin xxx. Las urls que ya estan indexadas siguen esta forma: www.prueba.com/diccionario/banderas/europa/espana pero ahora quiero que las nuevas y todas las antiguas vayan a www.prueba.com/diccionario/banderas/europa/bandera-espana. "bandera-" siempre va a ser igual.

Comment: ¿Resolviste este problema o sigues con él? Disculpa que la dejara olvidada. Si quieres la retomamos haciendo uso del chat para hacer un par de pruebas.